# Printer Meter reading

Tags: .net, wpf, printing, protocols, snmp

I have come across a nice solution in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12120056/1834352) . Looks there must a way to find out the meter reading through SNMP. I have programmed and saw there were many properties and values but couldn't find the exact information for meter reads. I have used MIB browser to browse network connected printer MIB information.

In simple, how to read the printer meter through SNMP? Does SNMP contain this information?

Note: I only need OIDs. I have built the program already to read values through SNMP.

**Update:**

After a trail and error method I found few OIDs but not sure this ll work for all models of FujiXerox.

The below looks promising for most of the models, however would require a capture for all models,

```
".1.3.6.1.4.1.253.8.53.13.2.1.6.101.20.1",
".1.3.6.1.4.1.253.8.53.13.2.1.6.101.20.2",
".1.3.6.1.4.1.253.8.53.13.2.1.6.101.20.3",
".1.3.6.1.4.1.253.8.53.13.2.1.6.101.20.4",
".1.3.6.1.4.1.253.8.53.13.2.1.6.101.20.5",
```

Below are the once sometimes come up null, some times with values that are

```
".1.3.6.1.4.1.253.8.53.13.2.1.6.1.20.34",
 ".1.3.6.1.4.1.253.8.53.13.2.1.6.1.20.33", 
  ".1.3.6.1.4.1.253.8.53.13.2.1.6.1.20.7",
 ".1.3.6.1.4.1.253.8.53.13.2.1.6.1.20.29",
   ".1.3.6.1.4.1.253.8.53.13.2.1.6.103.20.3",
 ".1.3.6.1.4.1.253.8.53.13.2.1.6.103.20.25",
 ".1.3.6.1.4.1.253.8.53.13.2.1.6.1.20.71"
```

Is there a standard OIDs for all models?

Comment: Can you let us know which printer model? And preferable post the MIB file somewhere for us to download. Without this information, it's impossible to answer your question.

Comment: FujiXerox and Konica Minolta , I found few but apparently they are different from model to model, Is this not a standard for manufacturer?

Comment: Can you explain, how to find this information in MIB? Is there a way that we can identify just by looking at the OID or specific location? OID description is clear always and this information is lying in Private MIB manufacture specific.

Comment: The answer is "no", there is no standard printer MIB that all manufacturers must adhere to. The SNMP protocol is by design de-centralized, and each vendor may implement any MIB they choose. For printers, most manufacturers implement their own proprietary MIB. That's why you found different files for different models.

Comment: @Jolta Partially wrong. There is a semi-standard [Printer-MIB](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3805.txt) (`1.3.6.1.2.1.43`)that the majority of manufacturers, usually IN ADDITION to their proprietary MIB in Private (`1.3.6.1.4`) or, of course, they just don't do SNMP. Thats a possibility too.

Comment: Thanks for that, Psychodata, I had managed to miss that one.

Comment: I managed to solve this by looking at the data using MIB Browser and then got the OID s which then become static in my code and every time its been called it is promising and reliable in terms of reading meter. However I know there should be a way for generic solution to work with any model/make. Would be great to have at least.

Answer (score 0):

That wouldn't help much, but print vendors seem to not have common agreement on which OIDs should contain print meters. Besides, the very term print meter could mean various things. For example, pagePickedUp and pagesPrinted are two different metrics.
The best way is to ask the vendor directly. Some of them post this info on official site.